# Get the latest copy and email that to yourself

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I just started learning google script with no experience. I'm having trouble getting the newly created copy of the original document and sending that to myself. For some reason, it keeps sending the original one.

```
function Every Week() {  


ScriptApp.newTrigger("Weekly")  
.timeBased()  
.everyDays(7)  
.create();  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxx");   
DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("Loads and 
date"+sheet.getName(), destFolder);     

var files = DriveApp.getFiles();  
while (files.hasNext())   
var file = files.next();  
var id = file.getId();  
var lastUpdated = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();  

var MyLink = sheet.getUrl()   
var MyUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  
var files = DriveApp.g  
MailApp.sendEmail({ to: MyUser, subject: 'Weekly title', body: MyLink, }); 
} ;
```

I keep getting the original template instead of the new copy.

Comment: Welcome. I think that the next step is that you do your best to clean-up your code. There are several unnecessary code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
function Weekly() {
  var Found=false;
  var trgs=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<trgs.length;i++){
    if(trgs[i].getHandlerFunction()=="Weekly"){
      Found=true;
    }
  }
  if(!Found){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("Weekly").timeBased().everyDays(7).create();  
  }
  var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");   
  var newSpreadsheet=DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("New Title", destFolder);     
  var MyLink = spreadsheet.getUrl()   
  var MyUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();    
  MailApp.sendEmail(MyUser,'Weekly title',MyLink); 
}
```